# How to match regular expressions in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm using the following query:

```
select * from table
WHERE POSTAL_CODE LIKE '[a-Z][0-9][a-Z] [0-9][a-Z][0-9]';
```

However, this is not capturing anything. For example, a typical POSTAL_CODE looks like 'B3M 3K5'. Why would this not match?

Comment: The only think that will match is the string literal "[a-Z][0-9][a-Z] [0-9][a-Z][0-9]". As has been pointed out, you need (assuming Oracle >= 10) regexp_like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use [`regexp_like`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) not `like` if you want to use regular expressions.  It sounds like you want

```
with x as (
    select 'A1B C2D' postal_code from dual union all
    select 'XXX 777' from dual union all
    select 'a1B 2C3' from dual
 )
 select *
   from x
  where regexp_like( postal_code, '^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]$', 'i' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE` instead of `LIKE` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).